# Postgres SQL, Can filter on results less than 20 days but not results over 20 days

Tags: postgresql, looker

I have a dimension which I have declared called mystay_days_before_stay    and I have created a tier to group this information. When I query for results over 19 days then the query crashes.

```
dimension: mystay_days_before_stay {
  label: "Days before Stay"
  view_label: "MyStay"
  type: number
  sql: cast(${TABLE}.properties ->> 'days_before_stay' as Int) ;;
}

dimension: mystay_days_before_stay_tier {
  type: tier
  tiers: [7,30,90]
  style: integer # the default value, could be excluded
  sql: ${mystay_days_before_stay} ;;
}
```

I am unsure as to why it only returns results up until 19 days on the filter.

Comment: What language is this ?

Comment: Postgres SQL on Looker

Comment: Your LookML seems valid, if it runs when you're *not* filtering then it's mapping to your DB properly.  When you say "the query crashes" what exactly happens, do you get an error or does it simply return an empty result?

Comment: do yo have an error message to share?

Comment: For those asking, the language is called [LookML](https://docs.looker.com/data-modeling/learning-lookml/what-is-lookml)

Comment: Can you share the SQL query that Looker generates when you run the report that's failing?